# Ruby on Rails new application error: no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just installed Ruby, RubyGems, and Rails on Ubuntu 10.04. Now I tried to create a new application:

```
rails new blog
```

and it returns an error:

```
run  bundle install
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- net/https (LoadError)
...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
```

Comment: It went past that error, but got stuck here instead:

Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: Try it: apt-get install libsqlite3-dev